# How to ask forgiveness for bad intention?

Tags: allah

I am extremely sorry for disturbing you. I am asking the same question again. Nothing is working. I just can't be in peace. Yes what i wished at that moment, i actually meant it. I actually wanted woman to get cheated by their husbands  but later i changed my intention. But still I feel like i will get cheated by my husband too. Please help me. Please..

Answer (score 1):

Tell them (o prophet),"My servants who have committed excesses against themselves (committed sins) do not lose hope in Allah's mercy. Surely Allah forgives all sins(with repentance). He is the most forgiving,most merciful.
Don't worry, Allah will forgive you,if you repent , everyone does mistakes but the best of them is the one who repents. You are sorry for this,so Allah will not punish you,he is very merciful.

Answer (score 1):

Almighty Allah will forgive every sin except **Shirk**. You haven't committed any **Shirk** in this case. Repent by reciting **Astaghfirullah** more frequently. Try to do **Sadaqah** and make dua to the Almighty Allah to make things easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

Allah forgives all sins. People who are saying he does not forgive except certain sins is not accurate at all, since Shirk is not forgiven when the person dies. But for your case, as long as you ask forgiveness, Allah will forgive you. And don't forget, Allah is how his believers think of. If you think Allah will forgive you the moment you say astaghfirullah, he will do so.